# What is the opposite of "in-image ads"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

The term *in-image ads* describes ads that are inside of images. What would be the term that describes ads that are outside of images?

Could it be *out-image ads*?

Comment: You would call them *ads*. There is no need to relate them to an image, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do call them ads, but here I want to distinguish them from *in-text* ads.

Comment: Could you provide an example where it maybe used? I can only think of *In-text advertising, In-image advertising, and Ads*. As in your case, the opposite could be *in text advertising, or ads*. If it's not *in-image*, then it's one of the others.

Comment: On a different note, *in image* means *image based*, even though the ad may well be embedded in an image.

Comment: It's a bit technical. I'm tracking clicks and I'd like to track *in-image ads* separately from the rest.

Comment: You yourself use "in-text". Perhaps you could edit your question to include screen-shot extracts showing what you mean.

Comment: As @Andrew mentioned the question needs additional detail. It may well get closed if you leave it as is.

Comment: Maybe the more general term of a [contextual ad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contextual_advertising), which has subcategories of in-image advertising and in-text advertising, would work.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia contrasts in-image advertising with in-text advertising.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-image_advertising

Answer (score 1):

An *in-image ad* is a subtype of *advertisements*. There isn't really an opposite, just as there's no opposite of a dalmatian when thinking about dogs. To describe the everything except the particular subtype, you have to explicitly make the exclusion.

So, as we could say *dogs other than dalmatians*, we would need to say *adverts other than in-image ads*, *non-in-image ads*, or something equivalent.